# How do I read error messages in ruby and ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I get a big error message in Ruby or Ruby on Rails and I don't understand it, how can I decipher the error message **before** posting it to stack overflow. Are there any tools tips or techniques that will help me get to the bottom of error messages, and find the code that is actually having the problem?

Comment: I suppose some code could help this question, but mainly I wanted to do this because I see a HUGE amount of questions with a stack trace asking for the problem to be fixed, and when it is so easy to read RoR error messages, I figured I would write a community wiki hoping to reduce clutter

Answer (score 3):

Error messages in Ruby and Ruby on Rails are actually quite clear if you look at them closely. The "stack trace" is actually really helpful. It shows you the three things you will need most to solve the problem:

1. The paths of all the files involved
2. The line numbers of those files
3. The name of the block that the error occurred in. Example:

   ```
   C:\Users\krishnac\Documents\NetBeansProjects\githupbdcm\trunk>bundle exec rake 
   rake aborted!
   incompatible library version - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1.rc1-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt_ext.so
   C:/Users/krishnac/Documents/NetBeansProjects/githupbdcm/trunk/config/application.rb:13:in <top (required)>'
   C:/Users/krishnac/Documents/NetBeansProjects/githupbdcm/trunk/Rakefile:5:in require'
   C:/Users/krishnac/Documents/NetBeansProjects/githupbdcm/trunk/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
   `(See full trace by running task with --trace)`
   ```

So now that we have the message

1. We can tell by reading this that the error can be traced to the file

   ```
   C:/Users/krishnac/Documents/NetBeansProjects/githupbdcm/trunk/Rakefile:5
   ```

   This doen't necessarily mean that the error occured in this file, but one of the methods that got called leading up to the error **is in this file**.
2. The `:5` indicates that the fifth line is where the error occurs.
3. The next part of that tells us the error occurs in the block `require`:

   ```
   Rakefile:5:in 'require'
   ```

So you see, reading error messages isn't so bad. All we have to do is look through until we find **the file we know is relevant** and then we find the **line number we want** and then we fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Ruby on Rails gives you a location and description of the error. That way, you don't need to post the errors to SO.

As a rule of thumb, it's good practice to look at the first error message that appears in the script and fix that first. Often times one error will cause more errors in your program and fixing them will resolve others.

Lastly, a useful tool would be to use a debugger. This gem allows you to stop your code at suspected errors and read the code line by line. The documentation can be found on GitHub here: https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger